# Executar e controlar uma aplicação

Tags: visual-basic-6

Usei código VB para,

1. Executar e Ativar uma Aplicação
2. Preencher (user, pass) de acesso
3. Ativar no menu o item pretendido
4. Enviar comandos para registar, filtrar, consultar ou imprimir dados

Os itens do menu são ativados com o rato,
sem *Short Key* nem *Tab Stop*. É possível em VB, ativar um item, num menu deste tipo?

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida, se diz *"Usei código VB para....3.Ativar no menu o item pretendido"* me parece que já conseguiu, depois pergutas *"É possível em VB, ativar um item, num menu deste tipo?"*, isso não consegui entender

Comment: não consegui ativar o item.

Comment: intercalei uma msgbox a informar o user para ativar o item e
reativei a aplicação para retomar o control.